# why an extra comma in the shape of a single index numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

A numpy array a
   a = numpy.arange(12)

has shape
a.shape = (12,)

Why do we need the comma? is shape (12) reserved for something else?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason we don't use `(12)` for a one-element tuple (like `[12]` for one-element list) is that round parentheses also appear in formulas. E.g., in `x = 2*(5+7)` the part `(5+7)` is just a number, not a tuple. But what if we actually meant it to be a one-element tuple? The trailing comma is a way to indicate that. Compare:

```
>>> 2*(5+7)
24
>>> 2*(5+7,)
(12, 12)
```

With lists, the trailing comma is not needed although some style guides recommend it for consistency.

```
>>> 2*[5+7]
[12, 12]
>>> 2*[5+7,]
[12, 12]
```

Answer (score 9):

A numpy array's shape property always returns a tuple.

> The number of dimensions and items in an array is defined by its `shape`, which is a tuple of N positive integers that specify the sizes of each dimension.

`(12,)` is just a one-element tuple, so this indicates that you have a one-dimensional array (because the tuple has length 1) with a size of `12`.

Documented [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html).