# Python Numpy coding library

Tags: python, numpy

What does this mean in numpy coding, `(4,)`? You have an array and you run the shape of it and it gives you this answer. What does it mean?

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.shape

(4,)
```

Comment: check the doc : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Comment: And another recent question asking by the extra comma: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134891/why-an-extra-comma-in-the-shape-of-a-single-index-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's `.shape` property is a `tuple` that contains the size of the numpy object in every dimension.

Since your object is one-dimensional (a regular array), the length of the tuple is 1. Since your one-dimensional object contains 4 objects, it's size in the first dimension is 4, so the first element in the tuple is 4.

If the notation is confusing, `tuple([4]) == (4,)`. The trailing comma is necessary because `(4)` would simply be regular parenthesis around an expression.

If your numpy object was a two-dimensional array of size 3x4, the `.shape` would give `(3, 4)`.