# Isn't this a row vector?

Tags: numpy

```
 v = np.array([1,2,3])
    In [17]: v.shape
    Out[17]: (3,)
```

Why isn't the shape [,3]? Because it has only one row and three columns. Isn't it a row vector?

Comment: It's an 1d array. Arrays have no orientations. They just have Dimensions.

Comment: "They just have dimensions". Isn't the dimension "1 by 3"?

Comment: There is no such thing as `(, 3)` in Python. See also [Difference between these array shapes in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27570756) and [why an extra comma in the shape of a single index numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46134891)

Comment: Why just 1 by 3?  Why not 1 by 1 by 3 by 1?  Addi g those extra dimensions is just a convenience for humans.  The code has no problems working with 1d arrays.  Python lists are 1d.